# SWUpdate with wrong mmc device address

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, swupdate

I use this sw-description with device="/dev/mmcblk3p1", but swupdate will download files to "/dev/mmcblk3p2".

```auto
files: (
            {
                  filename = "zImage";
                  path = "/zImage";
                  device = "/dev/mmcblk3p1";
            },
            {
                  filename = "imx6dl-sabresd.dtb";
                  path = "/imx6dl-sabresd.dtb"
                  device = "/dev/mmcblk3p1";
            }
         );
```

Comment: Please, do not use *images* for show the **text**. Instead, copy-paste the text directly into the question post. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/sw-description.html#files) for the `files` section:

> Entries in `files` section are managed as single files. The attributes `filename` and `path` are mandatory. Attributes `device` and `filesystem` are optional; they tell SWUpdate to mount device (of the given filesystem type, e.g. `ext4`) before copying `filename` to `path`.
>
> Without `device` and `filesystem`, the `filename` will be copied to `path` in the current rootfs.

You have specified `device` but not `filesystem`, therefore SWUpdate [ignores](https://github.com/sbabic/swupdate/blob/2021.04/handlers/raw_handler.c#L211) the `device` attribute, and copies your files to whichever filesystem is already mounted at `/`.

You need to specify `filesystem` e.g. `ext4`.